# Set custom image background to children of an expandablelistview

Tags: android, image, background, expandablelistview

I need ExpandableListview with custom child background like below, any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: https://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

Comment: what you have tried?